# How do I get my backgroun image to display behind the text in my header using CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I tried checking everything I could to ensure that the image is referenced properly so it can display in my banner but nothing seems to work.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <header id="header">
     <h1> Most Loved Place on Earth</h1>
  </header>
```

My CSS3:

```
  header {font-family: journalregular;
  font-size: 250%;
  text-align: center;
   color:#B22222;
   **background-image: url("images/cover.jpg");}**
```

The image is in the right folder, and I am using the right extension. I tried the URL without the quotes as well. Help!

Comment: Your code seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/554y4wf6/

Comment: The path is wrong for sure. Open CSS file in separate tab, and see what's it's path.

Comment: Check your network tab in dev console and see if the image is being loaded in, this code should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the image path have to be refered in relation of you css path, in your code example, image is located on image folder and shared the same root of css file.

If your css is locadte for example:

```
rootfolder/css/nameofcssfile.css
```

and your images is located in:

```
rootfoder/images/backgroundfile.jpg
```

So the reference have to be:

```
background-image: url(../images/cover.jpg);
```

image path with or without quotes, I prefer without quotes

Comment: just to note, the image path can have quotes - but this should solve his problem.

Comment: only for better explain of quotes in url: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri

Comment: sorry, just read your answer again - I thought you said it must not have quotes - my bad